# UWP Frame auto resize contents inside

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I got a window with a frame:

< Frame VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
Height="Auto"/>

And I want to fit in another window inside there. However, unless I hardcode the height, the Window will stay half empty, since its contents are sometimes not fully covering the Frame.

Briefly, I have a Frame, in which I have a new Page, which has a Grid with 3 rows and they are of variable size depending on input from other parts. If the amount of contents is too small, the Window does not stretch, if the amount of contents is too big, the 3 rows go off the screen. I tried binding the height to its parent but that only seems to initially set the height and is not responsive to resizing of the App window.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **SizeChanged** event tied to controls like Frame or Grids, and update the size in that event to keep it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're including another view in the frame, you should not do anything special for this... Could you explain more ?